# Make nav item arrow change on hover

Tags: html, css

Whenever I hover on menu item I want the arrow to change up. Also when user is still hovered on the submenu the arrow should be up unless the user leaves the submenu/menu item. How can I achieve this? Should this be done using js or it can be done with css only? Not sure how to approach this.

The correct class on icon would be `chevron-up`

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgrey;
  top: 40px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-text">
      Test
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>

    <div class="nav-submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-text">
      Test
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>

    <div class="nav-submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-text">
      Test
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>

    <div class="nav-submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, pure CSS:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgrey;
  top: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.nav-item:hover .fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-text">
      Test
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>

    <div class="nav-submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-text">
      Test
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>

    <div class="nav-submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-text">
      Test
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>

    <div class="nav-submenu">
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```